# Using unmanaged dlls in sharepoint farm solution

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, solution-package, farm-solution

I have a SharePoint 2016 project with several application pages (farm solution).

In my code, I use un-managed dlls with `DllImport` attribute. To use them, I copy these dlls to System32 folder.

Is there a better way to use these libraries with WSP?

How to automatically deploy them?